# Connect to Virtual Machine using AAD Account

Tags: azure-active-directory, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

I am unable to login my office 365 account on my virtual machine. This my logs when I run  dsregcmd /status on cmd.

I tried to edit the VM using this command, still not working.
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2

Also, I added Role assignment: Virtual Machine Administrator Login and Virtual Machine User Login

And I have this on my extension: AADLoginForWindows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

While creating virtual machine in **management** Make sure to check login with Azure Ad like below:

[image]

In your virtual machine check whether ***extension*** is added:

[image]

Try to assign role assignment **`Virtual Machine User Login`** or
**`Virtual Machine Administrator Login`** to user

Now, Download Rdp file and login. When I tried to check with **`dsregcmd /status`** Azure AD joined successfully:

[image]

To Login with Azure Ad credentials account try to change **Network Level Authentication** access in RDP to avoid an error:

In RDP -> search box type *allows remote connection to this computer* -> uncheck the box like below:

[image]

Now edit your RDP downloaded file, try to include

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
username:s:xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com (Add your username here)
domain:s:AzureAD
```

[image]

When I try to connect with login **`AzureAd\UPN`** with user it connected successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: After i edited the  RDP using this : enablecredsspsupport:i:0 ,authentication level:i:2. I am unable to log my AD account.

Comment: Use Azure\username in login and can you include what error you are getting?

Comment: Incorrect password and username. I had also configure the Azure AD account, using this documentation :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/tutorial-single-forest. Unable to connect it using the office 365 account. Please need help and assistance. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Check this reference https://youtu.be/4Hv5NYhhQJ8 to more in detail

Comment: I can now log by setting the group policy but the problem now is I am seeing different session. How to have a VM that has the same session with multiple users? thanks

Comment: How to accept it?